# Upgrade of 17.10 on about 2017-12-19 made it unusable due to random clicks

Tags: upgrade, touchpad

Upgraded my 17.10 on or about Dec 19, 2017 and suddenly random clicks did things like bring up screen keyboard, open new tabs, log off, scroll, enlarge screen, etc. etc

HP laptop.  I disabled the touch screen and the touch pad (that is my normal way) and that was no help.

I booted up in Windows, no problem.  I booted up in a previous version of 17.10 and no problem.

I think there is a bad bug in the latest update.

Comment: Hmmm. My HP Touchscreen desktop has the same updates and seems fine.

Comment: I think my laptop had a faulty touch screen from the get-go so I have always disabled it.  My working theory is the latest upgrade has something wrong with the code that disables the touch screen.

Comment: A 'faulty touch screen' may be an electrical short somewhere among your inputs. Disabling inputs may not help if the short can find another path - shorts are good at that. We cannot help you much with defective hardware.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is most likely caused by a hardware failure.